# get value attribute of hidden input field in symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 5 and php7.

```
{{ form_widget(form.groupTab) }}<input type="hidden" id="ce-participants__type" data-field="app_registration_group_type_form[groupTab]" value="0">
```

I want to get the value attribute within the hidden input field. It should return '0' as string.

In my controller I`ve tried following:

```
$groupTab = $form->get('groupTab')->getViewData();
```

but I always get an empty string as response => ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your hidden field has no `name` attribute, so I'm not even sure you *can* get its value back.

You should create that field with the form builder, just as you do the groupTab field. Then you can get its value with `$form->get('yourHiddenField')->getData()`.

Comment: thx, coworker making FE skeleton said it is not necessary, which is true but means more work --> bottom line: your suggestion worked for me.